# Random insert and random rotation

Tags: jquery

I'm inserting images inside a div in random order.

I would like to also rotate the images randomly. I have Jquery and a rotate-plugin for jquery that works simply by typing something like 
    $("#img").rotate(45);

Here is my code for the random order of the images:

```
var contents=new Array (

'<img class="karkki" class="omenalaku" src="images/omenalaku01.png"      onclick="image_control001();" alt="omenalaku" />',

'<img class="karkki" class="omenalaku" src="images/omenalaku02.png" onclick="image_control002();" alt="omenalaku" />',

'<img class="karkki" class="omenalaku" src="images/omenalaku03.png" onclick="image_control003();" alt="omenalaku" />',

'<img class="karkki" class="omenalaku" src="images/omenalaku04.png" onclick="image_control004();" alt="omenalaku" />',

'<img class="karkki" class="omenalaku" src="images/omenalaku05.png" onclick="image_control005();" alt="omenalaku" />',

'<img class="karkki" class="omenalaku" src="images/omenalaku06.png" onclick="image_control006();" alt="omenalaku" />',

'<img class="karkki" class="omenalaku" src="images/omenalaku07.png" onclick="image_control007();" alt="omenalaku" />',

'<img class="karkki" class="omenalaku" src="images/omenalaku08.png" onclick="image_control008();" alt="omenalaku" />',

'<img class="karkki" class="omenalaku" src="images/omenalaku09.png" onclick="image_control009();" alt="omenalaku" />',

'<img class="karkki" class="omenalaku" src="images/omenalaku10.png" onclick="image_control010();" alt="omenalaku" />'
);

// insert elements in random order inside the candybox div
var i=0
//variable used to contain controlled random number 
var random

//while all of array elements haven't been cycled thru
while (i<contents.length){
    //generate random num between 0 and arraylength-1
    random = Math.floor(Math.random()*contents.length)
        //if element hasn't been marked as "selected"
    if (contents[random]!="selected"){
        $(".candybox").append(contents[random]);
        //mark element as selected
        contents[random]="selected"
        i++
    }
}
```

Is it possible to insert the random rotation into the same while loop? My attempts resulted in every image having the same amount of rotation. I would like each image to have a different rotation value.

EDIT:

Here is myy feeble attempt:

```
// insert elements in random order inside the candybox div
var i=0
//variable used to contain controlled random number 
var random

//while all of array elements haven't been cycled thru
while (i<contents.length){
    //generate random num between 0 and arraylength-1
    random = Math.floor(Math.random()*contents.length);
    randomrot = Math.floor(Math.random()*360);
    //if element hasn't been marked as "selected"
    if (contents[random]!="selected"){
        $(".candybox").append(contents[random]);
        contents[random].rotate(randomrot);
        //mark element as selected
        contents[random]="selected"
        i++
    }
}
```

This results in console error `Object <img class="karkki" class="omenalaku src="images/omenalaku03.png" onclick="image_control003();" alt="omenalaku" /> has no method 'rotate'`. Seems like I'm trying to accessing the rotate-plugin incorrectly to the DOM element, but how to do it properly?

Comment: Yes, you can use `var rotation = Math.random() * 360;` after your other `Math.random` and then use the jquery plugin to rotate the element by the `rotation` amount.

Comment: It seems like contents[random] is a string. There is no 'rotate' method on a string.

Answer (score 0):

Replace these 2 lines:

```
$(".candybox").append(contents[random]);
contents[random].rotate(randomrot);
```

with this:

```
contents[random].appendTo(".candyBox").rotate(randomrot);
```

Comment: Hi! With that I get console error saying <img class="karkki" class="omenalaku" src="images/omenalaku09.png" onclick="image_control009();" alt="omenalaku" /> has no method 'appendTo'